# Android Studio 3.1 Где находится TimePicker в редакторе макетов

Tags: android-studio

В обновлении 3.1 не могу найти TimePicker. В версии 3.0 все было. Что теперь делать? Как вывести часы? [image: снимок экрана]

Comment: вы всегда можете набрать код в xml-файле разметки (ввести нужный виджет вручную)

Comment: Это (известный) баг. Вводите вручную. Свойства можно будет редактировать во вкладке Дизайн как обычно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо!